# If string is "NA - NA", change value to a variable value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing three columns of strings, if the value of Col3 is "NA - NA", then it should be replaced by "Col1 - Col2".

How can I add this to my script?

Comment: Try `with(df1, replace(Col3, Col3=="NA - NA", "Col1 - Col2"))`

Answer (score 1):

without a full reproducible example all i can tell you is this:

```
df$Col3[df$Col3=="NA-NA"]="Col1-Col2"
```

add a reproducible question and a little more detail for a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, it gets me half way there, but would it be possible to get it so it gives the value in col1 and col2 using paste?

Comment: So you want the NA-NA to be replaced with the value of df$Col1-Col2?

Comment: df<-data.frame(c("0800 - 1830", "NA - NA", "0800 - 1300"), c("<NA>", "Holiday", "<NA>"), c("NA", 8, "NA"))
colnames(df)<-c("Worked.Hours", "Pay Code", "Hours")

Comment: So, for the second row of this, Worked.Hours would be equal to "Holiday - 8 hrs"